# Serializing Tree into nested list using python

Tags: serialization, tree, nested

I have a binary tree class like this:

```
class BinaryTree:
def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

Now I'm facing a task to serialize this structure in to a nested list. BTW, I have a left-to-right traversal function in mind:

```
def binary_tree(tree):
    if tree:
        for node_data in binary_tree(tree.left):
            yield node_data
        for node_data in binary_tree(tree.right):
            yield node_data
```

Or there is a general way to serialize it into mixed nested structure? For example, {[]}, or [{}]?

Answer (score 0):

as a method of `BinaryTree`:

```
def to_dict(self):
    data = self.data
    left = self.left
    if left is not None:
        left = left.to_dict()
    right = self.right
    if right is not None:
        right = right.to_dict()
    return {'data':data, 'left':left, 'right':right}
```

and as a class method of `BinaryTree`:

```
def from_dict(cls, D):
    data = D['data']
    left = D['left']
    if left is not None:
        left = cls.from_dict(left)
    right = D['right']
    if right is not None:
        right = cls.from_dict(right)
    return cls(data, left, right)
```

Comment: But this only returns a one node. Is it possible to return a whole tree as a nested data structure?

Comment: @georgehu it does return the whole tree.